# How to prevent Grails from trying to use a domain class with Service in name as a service?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a domain class in my application named ContractedService. However, grails seems to recognize this as a service class (even though it's located in the grails-app/domain directory). How can this be prevented without completely renaming the class?

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Cannot add Service class [class com.myapp.ContractedService]. It is not a Service!
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:750)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:474)
    at grails.test.mixin.services.ServiceUnitTestMixin.mockService(ServiceUnitTestMixin.groovy:46)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension$FixtureType$FixtureMethodInterceptor.intercept(JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension.java:145)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.invokeTargetMethod(MethodInvocation.java:91)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:85)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.AbstractRuleInterceptor$1.evaluate(AbstractRuleInterceptor.java:37)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntimeJunitAdapter$1$2.evaluate(TestRuntimeJunitAdapter.groovy:48)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.TestRuleInterceptor.intercept(TestRuleInterceptor.java:38)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.invokeTargetMethod(MethodInvocation.java:91)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:85)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.AbstractRuleInterceptor$1.evaluate(AbstractRuleInterceptor.java:37)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntimeJunitAdapter$3$4.evaluate(TestRuntimeJunitAdapter.groovy:74)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.ClassRuleInterceptor.intercept(ClassRuleInterceptor.java:38)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: This may not sound too helpful, but you really should rename the class. Even if you can prevent Grails from treating it as a service, every developer who opens it up is going to expect to see a service, not a domain class. Naming is hard! :)

Comment: Not only that, but Grails is based on the idea of coding by convention. When you break convention, you break Grails. (So to speak). I think you should rename the Domain class.

Comment: Fair enough and I probably will to move forward, but I would still be interested in knowing the answer. It would seem like an easy things to do to make service discovery dependent on path, since domain objects and services should be on different paths.

Answer (score 2):

You should stick with the grails conventions. Therefore you may rename your domain class to something like ContractedServiceDefinition and use the original domain name table mapping:

```
static mapping = { table:'contracted_service'}
```

Comment: Sure, but as I understand it, the convention is to place services in the grails-app/services directory. I'd argue that only classes which end in Service and are placed in that directory should be recognized as services, and this seems to be consistent with the documentation. In this case, a domain class is being recognized as a service. Seems like a bug to me.